# Is it possible for a==a to evaluate false for some variable a in Java?

Tags: java

I've been posed this slightly obscure but interesting question about the behavoir of Java. Any ideas?

Comment: Thats like saying is it possible for 1==1 to be false? Unless of course there would by some kinda threaded/concurrency based change while that evaluation was happening. Thats the only reason I can think of.

Comment: guess I was wrong! =P Didn't know about Double.NaN sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for `float` or `double` `NaN`s (but not `Float` or `Double`). [Section 4.2.3 of the JLS 3rd Ed.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3) I believe IEEE 754 defines the operation that way. Those are the only cases.

Comment: really? How if its the same variable?

Comment: ah ok. So I'm not a Java person, was thinking of this from a C# perspective.

Comment: @giddy - it is the same in C#, and quite a standard for floating point number (double-precision floating-point numbers): [Double.NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Yep, Try this...

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double a = Double.NaN;
    if( a == a ) System.out.println("equal");
  }
}
```

http://www.ideone.com/K0d2j

Comment: Cheers very much @st0le and @Richard

Answer (score 1):

As giddy said, concurrency can mess it up. I just tried this:

```
public class Madness {

    private static volatile long a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long good = 0;
        long bad = 0;

        new Thread() {
            {
                setDaemon(true);
            }

            public void run() {
                while (true)
                    a++;
            }
        }.start();

        long print = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;

        while (true) {
            if (a == a)
                good++;
            else
                bad++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > print) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%d / %d", good, bad));
                print = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output was:

```
19936409 / 382
38360780 / 640
56895813 / 898
75827635 / 1159
94500958 / 1423
113184503 / 1701
131711068 / 1960
150423573 / 2239
168898106 / 2509
```

Admittedly, this is a case specifically designed to cause this. Removing the volatile on `a` changes things. I see some initial "bad" hits, but then it seems to be all good. I haven't investigated, but I have a feeling it's something to do with hot spot optimizing the code after some number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The code for Double.isNaN()

```
static public boolean isNaN(double v) {
    return (v != v);
}
```

This sounds like an interview questions.  A similar questions when is `x == x + 0` false which has more answers. ;)